# React Component keeps re-rendering/reloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to React currently doing my first react project. I can't figure out the issue here. Below is my code. User is redirected from another page to this page when they entered their search team and click search.

```
const Result = () => {
const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [routes, setRoutes] = useState([]);
  const { from, destination } = useParams();
  const [departureLocation, setDepartureLocation] = useState(from);
  const [destinationLocation, setDestinationLocation] = useState(destination);
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
          navigate('/result/' + departureLocation + '/' + destinationLocation);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
     refreshRoutes();
  }, []);

  const refreshRoutes = () => {
        API.get("routes/")
        .then((res) => {
            setRoutes(res.data);
        })
  };
  return (
    <div className = "container mt-5">
      < div className = "row" >
        <div className="col-md-4">
          <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="mt-4">
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicGenre">
              <Form.Label>Departure Location</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control as="select" 
                value={departureLocation}
                onChange={(e) => setDepartureLocation(e.target.value)}>
                  <option value="jajarkot">Jajarkot</option>
            </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicStarring">
              <Form.Label>Destination Location</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control as="select"
                placeholder="Enter Destination Location"
                value={destinationLocation}
                onChange={(e) => setDestinationLocation(e.target.value)}>
                  <option value="palpa">Palpa</option>
              </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-8 m">
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th className="table-light" scope="col">ID</th>
                <th className="table-light" scope="col">Company Name</th>
                <th className="table-light" scope="col">Departure</th>
                <th className="table-light" scope="col">Destination</th>
                <th className="table-light" scope="col">Departure</th>
                <th className="table-light" scope="col">Arrival</th>
                <th className="table-light" scope="col">Departure Date</th>
                <th className="table-light" scope="col">Price</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {routes.map((route, index) => {
                return (
                  route.departureLocation === from && route.destinationLocation === destination ?
                  <tr key="">
                    <th className="table-light" scope="row">{route.vehicleID}</th>
                    <td className="table-light"> {route.name}</td>
                    <td className="table-light"> {route.destinationLocation}</td>
                    <td className="table-light"> {route.departureLocation}</td>
                    <td className="table-light"> {route.departureTime}</td>
                    <td className="table-light"> {route.arrivalTime}</td>
                    <td className="table-light"> {route.departureDate}</td>
                    <td className="table-light"> {route.price}</td>
                  </tr>
                  : null
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When it is redirected to result page as `/result/kathmandu/gulmi` it does shows the data that matches the parameter. But whenever I click on the dropdown option, the filtered data is appended in the table. I can't figure out whats causing the issue.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please add more details.

Comment: Question title say - keeps re-rendering but in explanation you have not mentioned what is exactly re-rendering

Comment: What is rerendering/reloading? Please clarify more precisely what the issue is.

Comment: sorry if I worded it wrongly. So the issue is. When the table is first rendered the filtered data is shown. But whenever I select something from the dropdown, the same data is being appended below the table. So, The table has same filtered data twice after first time. Again when I click something from dropdown, same filtered data is again appended in the table.

Comment: Try using a valid React key when mapping the table rows. You should be seeing tons of React key warnings regarding duplicate keys.

Comment: Remember that useEffect is meant for code that ["leaves react"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect). It runs every single time render runs (after render completes), so if you make useEffect call refreshRoutes, and refreshRoutes calls setRoutes, and setRoutes updates the state value, that update triggers a render, which then runs your useEffect, which calls refreshRoutes, which calls setRoutes, which causes a render, which calls useEffect, which [...] So at the very least _don't call setRoutes_ if the result of refreshRoutes is the same data you already had.

Comment: (so at this point, rewriting your component as a class, with a one-time route update during `componentDidMount` would probably make a lot of sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only overt issue I see in your code is the React key used for the table data you are mapping. You are using the ***same key*** (*`key=""`*) for each table row. You should actually be seeing tons of React warnings about duplicate keys. The issue here is that when rendering lists/arrays React uses the key in the reconciliation process, and if the key doesn't change then React bails on rerendering. As you append data to your table React can't invalidate what it previously rendered and it remains on the screen.

See [Lists & Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more details.

The solution is to use a unique React key per table row, intrinsic id properties, like `vehicleID`, make for great React keys.

I suggest also running the `routes` array through a filter first, *then* mapping, it'll save the conditional rendering.

Example:

```
<tbody>
  {routes.filter((route) => 
     route.departureLocation === from && route.destinationLocation === destination
  )
    .map((route) => (
      <tr key={route.vehicleID}>
        <th className="table-light" scope="row">{route.vehicleID}</th>
        <td className="table-light">{route.name}</td>
        <td className="table-light">{route.destinationLocation}</td>
        <td className="table-light">{route.departureLocation}</td>
        <td className="table-light">{route.departureTime}</td>
        <td className="table-light">{route.arrivalTime}</td>
        <td className="table-light">{route.departureDate}</td>
        <td className="table-light">{route.price}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  )}
</tbody>
```